# BFQ I/O Scheduler

Tags: 14.04, kernel, disk, bfq

As you probably know, the BFQ scheduler drastically improves disk performances in a typical desktop usage scenario.

Now, I wanna try it on my 14.04.2, but all the guides I was able to find googling are a bit outdated (2012-2014).

Can someone explain how to get BFQ up and running? I think this kind of guide could be very useful for quite a few people.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean CFQ?..

Comment: no I mean BFQ. Is another scheduler.

Comment: Are you still using BFQ?

Comment: ...........Yep!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a PPA with pre-patched BFQ kernels for Trusty Tahr (14.04.2) its located [here](https://launchpad.net/~nick-athens30/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-bfq) but it is kernel 3.16 and i believe your looking for something more recent like 3.19 or 4.1 with bfq... i suggest you try to google on how to compile a custom kernel for ubuntu =)) so that you can maybe get pf-kernel work on ubuntu... but if you want the 3.16-bfq here are the.....

Terminal Commands for adding the bfq kernel ppa's

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nick-athens30/trusty-bfq
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-bfq linux-headers-generic-bfq

and if you have a later a kernel, say 3.19 ... you can easily change the default kernel grub boots into (if you want to boot to 3.16-bfq) using grub customizer which can be installed by

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

Comment: Thanks, I recompiled already with 4.0.4 and BFQ patches.